# Import from Archicad model fragmentation problem

Tags: import

I'm having a problem importing a model (Collada file) from Archicad to Blender (3.5). In the Object Mode the model looks fine but then when I switch to Edit Mode the geometry of the model gets fragmented into triangles... meaning that every plain object as wall is now fragmented. That makes adding textures to the model a nightmare. Is there any solution to fix it or is it easier just to create a new model in Blender?

---

[image: 3D viewport screenshot]

I have tried to add the texture to the fragments but it makes it very difficult or impossible to work with it...

Comment: Hello, would you mind adding a screenshot of your 3D viewport ? At first glance you should try Face > Tris to quads or ALT J with everything selected in edit mode

Comment: Hey! Yes I tried with Alt J command and it helped close to nothing...